# Using json field in mysql for page content

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I'm creating a website with laravel with a simple page builder where standard page have common fields but some other pages (like home) may have additional fields.
in this case is it good to use json field or another table like page_fields to store additional data?
I've seen many suggestion to avoid using json in term of performance and managing data (like where clause)
must note that in my case these fields will be used just to show them and also can be translated later

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Text would be more suitable along with some templating language like markdown to be stored in such column instead of pure html